# Are there any galaxies that spin "out of balance" as wet towels sometimes do in the washing machine spin cycle?

Tags: galaxy

Can a spinning galaxy be "out of balance" like wet towels in the spin-cycle?

Comment: Nice question! But can you please specify what do you mean by "out of balance" like in the analogy you gave?

Comment: No because the Galaxy would fly  apart with or ital speeds too strong for gravity..The towels are stopped by the container walls .

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_segregation_(astronomy)#Evaporation & https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/22710/16685

Comment: I was thinking, could the mass get unevenly distributed, perhaps when galaxies move into the gravitational field of another galaxy.